# Is there a way to wrap an &str to a &T(String) without cloning?

Tags: rust, struct, reference, cloning

In Rust, I frequently wrap Strings with custom structs for the purpose of disambiguating trait behavior. For example, I might have a data access trait called `IGetByField<T,F>` implemented like so:

```rust
pub struct ParentObjectId(pub String);

impl<'r> IGetByField<Object, ParentObjectId> for ObjectDao<'r> {
  fn get_by_field(&self, parent_object_id: &ParentObjectId) -> Vec<Org> {
    let connection = &mut unpool!(self.pool.get());
    DB::get_object_by_parent_id(connection, &parent_object_id.0)
  }
}
```

My question is, when invoking this method on the ObjectDao and wrapping a string ID, is there a way to go from a &str type to a &ParentObjectId without cloning the id reference?

i.e. my current code:

```rust
let some_parent_id: &str = "some_id";

let object = object_dao.get_by_field(&ParentObjectId(some_parent_id.clone()));
```

Is there a way to do this without cloning?

Comment: Would [Cow::Borrowed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) work?

Comment: This isn't possible because a `&str` need not point to the start of a `String`. For instance, from `let s = "string".to_owned(); let t = &s[1..];` there is no way to get `&s` back from `t`. Your best bet is probably to make a separate, borrowed version of `ParentObjectId`, or make it an enum similar to `Cow` (or have it just contain a `Cow`).

Comment: What is ParentOrgId? Your code shows ParentObjectId. In unsafe it is possible. Or change your structs, so you can take out an inner String. Or use reference counting. Or references with lifetimes. Depends on how your app works. Why you can't move the String in the POId and get from now on a ref to the String/&str from POId?

Comment: The memory of a String is in heap, &str can be in stack.

Comment: @BallpointBen I haven't worked with Cow much — looking at it it sounds like it roughly does what I want it to do though... can you help me understand how I would use it with the trait implementation though? If I still wanted the "ParentObjectId", could it wrap a Cow of the &str?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a will, there's a way:

```rust
fn foo(id: &str) {
    let frankenstring = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(unsafe { 
        String::from_raw_parts(id.as_ptr() as *mut u8, id.len(), id.len()) 
    });
    call_whatever_function_wants_the_string(&frankenstring);
}
```

This is of course pretty horrible, but it illustrates a point.

- A `String` is an owned buffer of bytes with a capacity and a length.
  It will deallocate this buffer when it is dropped.
  It's effectively a `Vec<u8>` that enforces itself to be `utf-8` encoded.
- A `&str` is a borrowed reference to a sequence of `utf-8` encoded bytes.

These two are not the same, and cannot be used interchangibly.
A `String` can give you a `&str`, but not the other way around.
Not every `&str` comes from a `String`, so a `&str` has no way of giving you a reference to a triple of `(pointer, length, capacity)` anywhere in memory that would represent itself.

*Note*: please don't use the above code snippet in production. While it will most likely work, it violates the safety invariants of `String::from_raw_parts` and therefore might become undefined behavior in future versions of Rust.

---

The problem that you have is **very** common though.
There are a few ways of solving this:

1. `Cow`. This type's whole purpose is to encapsulate this kind of dichotomy:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

pub struct ParentObjectId<'a>(pub Cow<'a, str>);

pub fn foo(id: &str) {
    let po = ParentObjectId(id.into());
    call_whatever_function_wants_the_po_id(&po);
}
pub fn bar(id: String) {
    let po = ParentObjectId(id.into());
    call_whatever_function_wants_the_po_id(&po);
}
```

2. Make your id type not require ownership: `struct ParentObjectId<'a>(&'a str);`. If you need to store `ParentObjectsIds`, use a separate type: `struct ParentObjectIdStored(String);`
3. Some sort of [string interning system](https://docs.rs/string-interner/latest/string_interner/) so you only have to pass around integer Ids.
4. Use `Rc` / `Arc` everywhere to avoid deciding on ownership at every function call boundary.
5. Just clone. Maybe that's fine.

... and probably many more. But I'll leave it at that for now.

Comment: This method is terribly unsound, and passing anything not created from `String` with this direct start pointer, length and capacity (for example, a string literal) will be immediate UB.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: This code does not meet any of the criteria for [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html). It also isn't unsound, as it does not allow any unrelated safe code to trigger UB. The created 'String' is only handed out immutably, and String has no API with interior mutability.  It is also never dropped, including panics. Though it does make assumptions about the implementation of `String`, that are not guaranteed by the standard library. So if their implementation changes, it might *become* unsound. That's why I said 'horrible'.

Comment: It _is_ UB, because it violates the safety preconditions for `String::from_raw_parts()`. This is not a language UB but a library UB, but it doesn't make it better.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: violating data structure invariants is not undefined behavior.

Comment: Violating the safety preconditions of an unsafe function, clearly documented under the "Safety" section, is definitely what we call UB and what should never be triggered in safe Rust.

Comment: In other words, `from_raw_parts()` is allowed to insert `unreachable_unchecked()` in this code. Or make it into lang UB in any other way.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such thing as 'library UB'. If you have a reference for that term, I would love to see it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: I added a note to make sure no one blindly copies this code. I hope that addresses your (valid) concerns, although we may slightly disagree on terminology :).

Comment: I still strongly disagree with this. **You should never ever trigger UB in Rust** (or any other language, really), and **this is UB**.